# Using VBA to run SQL Procedure and paste it to excel - Run time error 3704 - Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

I followed the  code from the Ownwise 56.7 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYq0ElVLZhg) to run a SQL procedure with VBA to excel, the code bellow works fine if the procedure is small and takes less than 30 seconds, for a larger procedures (60seconds) it gave me an error "Run time error 3704 - Operation is not allowed when the object is closed" when I am at line "ws.range("a2").copyrecordset rs"
I think it is saying that the recordset is close or empty, but it doesn't make sense because it worked for small procedure.
Any way to define the "commandtimeout=0" to the recordset?

(sorry but pasting the code didn't work as planed)

If you have a solution I will be very thankful.
cheers

```
Public Sub Get_Results_From_SP()

 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim NumResults As Long
Dim TotalOscars As Long
Dim AvgLength As Double
Dim AvgBoxOffice As Double
Dim wsReport As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim DatabaseName As String
Dim SQL As String
Dim querydate As String
Dim strConn As String
Dim NewFile As Workbook
Dim col As Integer
Dim tw As Workbook
Dim LWeekday As Integer
Dim Lmes, Lano, Ldia As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim FSO, f As Object
Dim Pth, Pth2, FileSource, FileDest As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = _
    "CommandTimeout = 0;" & _
    "Provider=PROVIDER NAME;" & _
    "Server=SERVER NAME;" & _
    "Database=DATABASE NAME;" & _
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
cn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE_NAME"
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

Set rs = cmd.Execute 

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    ws.Select
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        ws.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next I
ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Set ws = Nothing 

rs.Close
cn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense because the prior lines for example `rs.Fields(i).Name` work fine, so the recordset mustn't be closed. Do your fields show up on your excel sheet?

Comment: the fields don't show up on the excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution to the problem, but it is really strange.

I need to add "set nocount on" to my procedure.